# What happens if System.exit() is called again while a JVM shutdown is already in progress?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it no-op? Does the JVM avoid calling the shutdown hooks again?

For a use case, consider an UncaughtExceptionHandler that calls System.exit() for SomeException and then SomeException is thrown in two separate threads within a short period of time.

Also, assume that System.exit() is called in a new thread to avoid potential deadlocks.

**UPDATE**

As one of the comments rightfully pointed out, I should have tested this myself but I was lazy. The test below completes successfully irrespective of whether System.exit() is called in a regular or daemon thread and exits with code 1 after printing:

```
Requesting shutdown ...
Shutdown started ...
Requesting shutdown ...
Shutdown completed ...
```

And here is the code:

```
public class ConcurrentSystemExit {

  private final static boolean DAEMON = false;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    // Register a shutdown hook that waits 6 secs
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          System.out.println("Shutdown started ...");
          Thread.sleep(6000);
          System.out.println("Shutdown completed ...");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });

    // Define a Thread that calls exit()
    class ShutdownThread extends Thread {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Requesting shutdown ...");
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }

    // Issue first exit()
    Thread t1 = new ShutdownThread();
    t1.setDaemon(DAEMON);
    t1.start();

    Thread.sleep(3000);

    // Issue second exit()
    Thread t2 = new ShutdownThread();
    t2.setDaemon(DAEMON);
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Comment: System.exit halts the JVM **immediately**.  There is no "and then."  Unless you mean you are calling it from a shutdown hook?  In which case, I suspect you get in a recursive call resulting in a stack overflow.

Comment: @MadConan Well the call/function execution themselves take time.

Comment: @arshajii:  edited my comment while you were replying.

Comment: No, I haven't tested it. It's not something that renders itself to a simple unit test.

Comment: System.exit() does not halt immediately. It calls the shutdown hooks and these can take a while depending on what you do there. They may for instance wait for a long DB query to complete.

Comment: Doh!  my bad.  my foot tastes like chicken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit%28int%29) on `Runtime.exit()`:

> If this method is invoked after the virtual machine has begun its shutdown sequence then if shutdown hooks are being run this method will block indefinitely. If shutdown hooks have already been run and on-exit finalization has been enabled then this method halts the virtual machine with the given status code if the status is nonzero; otherwise, it blocks indefinitely.

Comment: So from here I would infer that the shutdown hooks are not invoked again and it's OK to invoke exit() multiple times as long as it's called in a separate daemon thread that would not prevent the JVM from terminating when blocked.

Comment: I don't think there's any thread where it blocking would prevent the JVM from terminating.

Comment: Correct. Once exit() is called, the daemon status of various threads is irrelevant. The JVM would just wait for the shutdown hooks to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your info, exit() method can throw SecurityException.

> Throws: SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its
>   checkExit method doesn't allow exit with the specified status.

[System (Java Platform SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

> ***What happens if System.exit() is called again while a JVM shutdown is already in progress?***

It depends on the security context, but in majority of cases nothing is executed after a call to the exit method, it just terminates the JVM.